# Deploying .NET/WPF application regularly for in-house testing

Tags: .net, wpf, testing, deployment

I want to give the current WPF project for testing to other people inside our company regularly during the application development.

What is the best way to do it?

Should I just deploy the application using ClickOnce or is there a better way to do it for regular in-house testing? The testing people don't want to open the project in Visual Studio nor do they need access to source code but only want to play around with the application.
I also need to give out new versions pretty frequently (like once a day or week) for testing and feedback.

Answer (score 1):

ClickOnce is certainly an option. You could also look into a continuous deployment solution like [InRelease](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/inrelease).

Answer (score 0):

If you want users to see and test changes often, you should definitely look into automating the process of getting code to them. ClickOnce will simplify the delivery/versioning of things (they just have to click a web url, and .NET will make sure they have latest version), but you still need to automate building and deploying the latest versions of your application.

I work for [Inedo](http://inedo.com/), and we have a lot of users who use [BuildMaster](http://inedo.com/buildmaster) for exactly this purpose. The workflow looks something like this...

1. Get Latest from $/MyApp
2. Build .NET Application (MyApp.csproj)
3. Prepare ClickOnce Application
4. Deploy to Testing Server

Of course you can add more steps like labeling, artifacts, email notification etc. There's actually a sample ClickOnce app (Calculator) in the example applications when you download BuildMaster.

Comment: can you provide a link to the sample clickonce app?